# border leaves space after applying padding to image

Tags: html, css, email, inline

I have an image that is floating to the right of a paragraph of text. So the text would not run right up to the image I had to pad the image. Now, the border recognizes the padding and leaves a white space between the image and the border.

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="140" height="190" style="float:right; padding-left:10px; border:2px solid black;">
```

This is for an email so I would like to keep the styles inline.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Here is the image tag in my code:
<img src="image.jpg" width="140" height="190" style="float:right; padding-left:10px; border:2px solid black;">

Comment: I would like for the border to butt up against the image and not be affected by the padding.

Comment: Tried using a margin instead of padding?

Comment: @user3233097 Then I would say you're looking for a `margin` rather than `padding`. You could **(a)** Apply a `margin-left` to the image, or **(b)** apply a `padding-right` to the paragraph...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image Padding in CSS, HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001903/image-padding-in-css-html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I can use margin but some email clients don't recognize margin so I usually put both margin and padding in the style. Is this a case where I should concede and not put padding in the style?

Comment: Post a jFiddle too, as it will help us better answer your question

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome's Inspect Element Tool gives a great example of how padding and borders operate on the DOM. Try using:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="140" height="190" style="float:right; margin-left:10px; border:2px solid black;">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using Margin instead..
read about box-model:

http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 0):

If `padding-left: val` is causing a white-space, you can try out

```
margin-left: val;
```

A `padding` is space added inside the boundary of the element whereas `margins` are added outside the boundary of the element!

Answer (score 0):

Margin is not supported 100% in html email, so stick to padding. Try adding the padding to your paragraph instead of the image. `padding-right:30px;` will result in the same positioning as `padding-left:30px;` on the image.

You should note though, that because this is html email, float does not work in all major clients (particularly Outlook), You should be using `align="left"` in a table element instead.